# Anonynous inner classes perfomace

Tags: java, android

Is there any perfomance loss when using anonymous inner classes?

Two approaches to SAX parsing are shown here [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/): using Default handler and Android wrapper classes. I wonder what is more effective(memory consumption, CPU usage)?

Comment: Several anonymous inner classes vs one named class with switch/if operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, an inner class makes next to no difference performance wise compared with a regular class.  The only difference is an inner class implicitly holds a reference to the outer class, which is a waste or 4-8 bytes if you don't need it. (But not a waste if you do need it)

> Several anonymous inner classes vs one named class with switch/if operators

A switch is likely to be the fastest option, but 99% of the time this is not the best reason to use it.

The question you should be asking yourself is; What is the simplest and clearest to write and maintain?  This is what you should do and most of the time this is what will optimise best as well.

If the code is relatively short and can easily put in one place I would use switch/if.  If the code is relatively lengthy, i.e. more than one screen full, you may want to break up the code and extracting methods or using anonymous classes may be an option.

Comment: that reference can sometimes be very expensive: if for example it prevents garbage collection

Comment: @Phillip JF, Good point. I have found this problem shows up pretty quickly in a memory profiler. ;) IMHO  Any field/method/inner class which can be made `static`, should be `static` I do this for clarity, but very occasionally for performance reasons.